# How to forcefully set the previously saved state of metrics in the prom-client registry?

Tags: prometheus, prom-client

My node.js application uses prom-client.
Once a minute, I save the current metrics to the database as a string.
How to install them in the registry back from the string?

```
async function saveMetricsToDatabase(dbSuite, register) {
  try {
    const metrics = register.metrics();
    const { metricsMapper } = dbSuite;
    await metricsMapper.create({ data: metrics }); // save into database
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to save metrics to database:', err);
  }
}
```

```
async function loadMetricsFromDatabase(dbSuite, register) {
  try {
    const { metricsMapper } = dbSuite;
    const result = await metricsMapper.findOne({
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
    });
    if (result) {
      const metrics = result.data;
      register.clear();

      register.xxx(metrics); // In the metrics variable, the past state of the metrics. 
                             // How to install them in the current registry?
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to load metrics from database:', err);
  }
}
```

Didn't find the preferred method in the technical documentation. Writing to the database is correct.
https://github.com/siimon/prom-client

Comment: I don't believe that any prometheus client has a functionality to set value for multiple metrics at once. Why would you want something like this?

Comment: After the application is restarted, the metrics are inherited and start with zero values. I am looking for a way to wind up metrics from the point of view, and not from the beginning

Comment: It might be not the wisest choice: imagine if prometheus will have a chance to scrape zero values between application start and counters "reinitialization". Are you sure you have a really good reason for this kind of behavior for your metrics?

Comment: what option can solve my problem?

Comment: Use metrics as everybody else: with counters resetting on restart. Functions like `increase` and rate deal with resets automatically. If you need something like "total value of counter" for whatever reason, you could use `increase(mymetric [8w])`, and adjust range selector according to your needs.

Comment: The customer is interested in counters with exact values. Increase the likelihood of this test? Could adding influxdb to prometheus as a repository solve the problem?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding a proxy wrapper over the prom-client library, which writes the metric increment to the database, and when the application is loaded, it winds up the metrics to the previous state (before the reboot). The increase function does not show the exact number of events. For example, if the metric appeared only today with an initial value of 5, and then was wound up by 1, then the increase shows 1, although 6 were changed.